# After restarting Mysql replication, Slave commands are executed

Tags: mysql, replication

up vote
0
down vote
favorite
I have a Mysql Master Slave Replication which is working fine. Unfortunately I got some serious problems on my slave and the only chance I saw was to restart the whole replication.

1. Slave was stopped
2. I created a dump on the master with logfile and logposition informations

   mysqldump --skip-lock-tables --single-transaction --flush-logs --hex-blob --master-data=2   > ~/dump.sql
3. I dropped the database on the Slave ( to enter the fresh data )
4. I inserted the fresh dump
5. Reset master log file and master position with information given from the dump file
6. Start Slave

Now everything worked fine for some minutes and I saw how the correct data was imported from the Master. But after 10 minutes, the slave stopped importing because there were some tables missing. After a second run, I found out, that the DROP DATABASE command, I executed on the Slave, was now executed again on the slave.

Even a RESET Slave and importing data then and proceeding from Step 3 didnt help.

How can I prevent that the commands, which have been executed on the slave since the DUMP, are not being executed again?

Comment: More specifics on step 2, please.

Comment: Edited step 2 for more details

Comment: hope your dump doesn't have drop database command written in it use grep -i "drop database" filename to verify it. what if you restore the dump using source filename command in mysql prompt and see where exactly you get this error..hope it helps

Comment: Is Step 5 done with a `CHANGE MASTER ...`?